Picture tag width bug in firefox
I have a problem with picture tag in firefox (latest)


.image-h-full picture{height:100%}
.image-h-full picture img{height:100%;width:auto;}
.image-x-center picture{display:flex;justify-content:center}

.border-1{border: 1px solid gray}
.border-black{border-color:black}
.rounded-20{border-radius:20px} 
.flex{display:flex}
.sh-60{height:60px}
.sw-60{width:60px}
.sw-500{width:500px}
.p-48{padding:48px}
.sw-full{width:100%}
.absolute{position:absolute}
.relative{position:relative}
.right-0{right:0}
.top-0{top:0}
.bottom-0{bottom:0}
.bg-black{background:#000}
.bg-blue{background:blue}
<div class="relative border-1 border-black rounded-20 p-48 sw-500">
<div class="sh-60 sw-60 bg-black">
</div>
<div class="absolute right-0 top-0 bottom-0 image-h-full image-x-center">
    <picture class="bg-blue">
      <img src="https://assets-global.website-files.com/64328ad759d957f990749456/661526e36b36425ec139b797_blog-banner-1%402x.png" alt="">
    </picture>
</div>
</div>



in chrome all good:

picture width same as img
But in Firefox picture set random width

How I can fix it? I can't set fixed width because content inside block need variable height

its not because the picture,  if you change to a div the issue remains, its the absolute, do you need this to be absolute ?

@dippas, yes, because parent block have a padding (not in this example) and I need set img position without paddings

show full working example then

@dippas I'm updated snippet in question
